# Select2 not populating hidden field with values

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-select2

I have select2 working in my WordPress plugin, and I am able to search for pages when I type into a field and click on them. You know how that works.

The problem is that the ids of the pages I select are not being added into the "exclusion_ids" hidden field. Here's my code:

```
<input name="exclusions" type="text" class="select2" />
<input name="exclusion_ids" type="hidden" />

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.select2').select2({
            ajax: {
                url: ajaxurl,
                dataType: 'json',
                delay: 250,
                data: function (params) {
                    return {
                        q: params.term,
                        action: 'search_posts',
                        nonce: '<?php echo wp_create_nonce( "search_posts_nonce" ); ?>'
                    };
                },
                results: function (data) {
                    var results = [];
                    $.each(data, function(index, post) {
                        results.push({
                            id: post.id,
                            text: post.title
                        });
                    });
                    return {
                        results: results
                    };
                },
                cache: true
            },
            minimumInputLength: 3,
            placeholder: 'Type to search for posts',
            tags: true,
            tokenSeparators: [',']
        });

        jQuery(document).on('change', '.select2', function() {
            var ids = [];
            $('.select2').find(':selected').each(function() {
                ids.push($(this).val());
            });
            $('input[name="exclusion_ids"]').val(ids.join(','));
        });
    });

    // Debugging
    jQuery(document).on('change', '.select2', function() {
        console.log('Change event fired!');
        var ids = [];
        jQuery('.select2').find(':selected').each(function() {
            ids.push(jQuery(this).val());
        });
        console.log('The ids :', ids);
        console.log('Hidden field value: ', jQuery('input[name="exclusion_ids"]').val());
    });
</script>
```

There are no errors in the console.

My debugging returns this:

```
Change event fired!

The ids : []
    length: 0
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)

Hidden field value:
```

When I inspect the hidden field while selecting a page from the field, I can see it suddenly change from this...

```
<input name="exclusion_ids" type="hidden">
```

...to this...

```
<input name="exclusion_ids" type="hidden" value="">
```

...so I do know the change event is firing and targeting the correct hidden field. So the problem looks like it's not getting the IDs.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I copied your code on my localhost but filled the select with predefined data instead of AJAX request, and it works fine, so probably something is wrong with your request.

Not sure what exactly you are requesting, but I guess it is WordPress posts, in WordPress id is uppercase, so it should be

```
id: post.ID,
```

not:

```
id: post.id,
```

I can be mistaken in that, because I do not 100% sure, what data is returned by your request. But for sure, issue is in the fetched data, not in the rest of the code.

To confirm, you can try do use static data as a source:

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 0,
        text: 'enhancement'
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        text: 'bug'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        text: 'duplicate'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        text: 'invalid'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        text: 'wontfix'
    }
];

    $('.select2').select2({
        data: data,
        minimumInputLength: 1,
        placeholder: 'Type to search for posts',
        tags: true,
        tokenSeparators: [',']
    });
```

Or log the $(this).val() to check what you are trying to push into array.

Hope this will help.

Comment: That was helpful. If I log `$(this).val()` as suggested I can see the page IDs are returned, for example: 44,65,95

So all I needed to do was add this to the on(change):

`$('#exclusion_ids').val(jQuery(this).val());` 

So the data is getting saved to the database, and I can return it in a variable called $exclusions but the select2 field doesn't show the pages that were selected. I though it would be as simple as doing this: `<input name="exclusions" type="text" class="select2" value="<?php if($exclusions) { echo esc_html($exclusions); } ?>" />` but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: According to the documentation, you need to do selection via jQuery, directly in your AJAX call, or later using standard syntax:
https://select2.org/programmatic-control/add-select-clear-items

Not sure if it is possible in PHP, do not know select2 that well.

Answer (score 0):

you have a bug in your code. you define `var ids` two times and so, you reset your values. this variable needs to be globally accessible. of course your array is empty in your "debugging" since you reset it (bc it doesn't exist).

and you may want to have a look at newer syntax `let` & `const` (basically, `let` is the new `var` and const is immutable (with exceptions though)), see [var let and const - whats the difference](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/)

```js
let ids = []; // set it here!

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    jQuery(document).on('change', '.select2', function() {
        var ids = []; // --> 1st time you set this variable
        // ...
    });
});

// Debugging
jQuery(document).on('change', '.select2', function() {
    console.log('Change event fired!');
    var ids = []; // --> 2nd time you set this variable
    // ....
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this

```
jQuery(document).on('change', '.select2', function() {
    var ids = [];
    $('.select2').find(':selected').each(function() {
        ids.push($(this).val());
    });
    $('input[name="exclusion_ids"]').val(ids.join(','));
});
```

and

```
jQuery(document).on('select2:select', '.select2', function(e) {
    var data = e.params.data;
    var ids = $('input[name="exclusion_ids"]').val();
    ids = ids ? ids.split(',') : [];
    ids.push(data.id);
    $('input[name="exclusion_ids"]').val(ids.join(','));
});
```